# Viewing HTTP headers from a POST request made to a web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use a google apps script web-app to receive push notifications on drive changes.  I have set it up so that any-time a drive change is made, a push notification is sent to the web-app I have created.  I am able to access the body of the POST using the event parameter in the doPost(e) method, but I cannot seem to access the http headers.
This is an issue because the information that I need to see is included in the X-Goog-Resource-State header.
Is it possible to view the headers of a post request made to a web-app from the web-app?
I have tried making an http request to the change's self-link, but the headers included are different than those provided in the initial push notification.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it currently isn't possible to access the request headers from Apps Script. Please file a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list